# Error in django unittest: 'object has no attribute' object

Tags: python-3.x, django, unit-testing, django-views

I started testing views, but I found an error in the test, tell me where I went wrong, I'm just starting to learn, so don't judge strictly
my views:

```
    `class MovieDetailView(Genre, DetailView):
            
            model = Movie
            slug_field = "url"
        
        
            def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
                context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
                context["star_form"] = RatingForm()
                return context
        `
```

my test looks like this:

```
        `def test_starform_set_in_context(self):
            request = RequestFactory().get('some-slug')
            view = MovieDetailView()
            view.setup(request)
            context = view.get_context_data()
            self.assertIn('star_form', context))`
```

url:

```
 `path("<slug:slug>/", views.MovieDetailView.as_view(), name="movie_detail"),`
```

Comment: show your complete traceback.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\endro\PycharmProjects\Django_movi\movies\Tests\test_views.py", line 35, in test_starform_set_in_context
    context = view.get_context_data()
  File "C:\Users\endro\PycharmProjects\Django_movi\movies\views.py", line 30, in get_context_data
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\endro\PycharmProjects\Django_movi\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\detail.py", line 94, in get_context_data
    if self.object:
AttributeError: 'MovieDetailView' object has no attribute 'object'

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because Django's get_context_data() function uses the 'object' to pass it into the context.So, I suggest you to use get_object() method.

See this for more details: https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/

basically you need to return an object e.g.

```
def get_object(self,queryset=None):
    obj = Movie.object.get(slug=self.kwargs.get('slug'))
    return obj #also handle 404
```

or try one more thing :

```
slug_fields = slug
```

**path should be**

```
path("<str:slug>/", views.MovieDetailView.as_view(), name="movie_detail"),
```

Comment: I changed in the test and I got an error: Generic detail view MovieDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf

Comment: oh I see, It should be path("<str:slug>/", views.MovieDetailView.as_view(), name="movie_detail"),

Comment: changed url error appeared:MovieDetailView' object has no attribute 'kwargs'